Is there an upper bound of ${_1F_1(1;a;x)}$?
As shown in the title, I want to calculate a closed-form upper bound of
$${_1F_1(1;a;x)}=\sum_{l=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^l}{(a)_l}.$$
If $a>x$, then an easy but tight upper bound can be obtained as
$$\sum_{l=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^l}{(a)_l}<\sum_{l=0}^{\infty}(\frac{x}{a})^l=\frac{a}{a-x}.$$
But in my exact problem, I do not have $a>x$, which means the bound is invaild. Can someone help me with this?

If you write, from definition
$$\,_1F_1(1;a;x) =\Gamma (a)\,e^x \,x^{1-a} \left(1-\frac{\Gamma (a-1,x)}{\Gamma(a-1)}\right)$$ the front factor could be a good idea.
Edit
Asymptotically,
$$\,_1F_1(1;a;x) =\Gamma (a)\,e^x\, x^{1-a}-\frac{(a-1) (a+x-2)}{x^2}+\cdots $$

If we assume that $a>1$ and $x>0$, then
\begin{align*}
{}_1F_1 (1;a;x) &= (a - 1)\int_0^1 {{\rm e}^{xt} (1 - t)^{a - 2} {\rm d}t}  = (a - 1)\,{\rm e}^x \int_0^1 {{\rm e}^{ - xt} t^{a - 2} {\rm d}t} 
\\ & = (a - 1)\,{\rm e}^x x^{1 - a} \int_0^x {{\rm e}^{ - s} s^{a - 2} {\rm d}s}  \le (a - 1)\,{\rm e}^x x^{1 - a} \Gamma (a - 1) \\ &= \Gamma (a)\,{\rm e}^x x^{1 - a} .
\end{align*}
For large $x$, this bound is asymptotically sharp.
